# Although layout has bootstrap view does not work

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I have added the bootstrap.css file to the head of layout;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
```

It appears on console of a page;

[image]

File is not empty I checked it

But bootstrap buttons look like;

[image]

When I add the bootstrap.css to the view page, it looks what it should look like.

How can I work out this problem ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is the view definitely using that layout page? Is there any other CSS used in the View which could cancel it out / change the style of the button? Chrome dev tools will allow you to inspect the element and see where the style definitions are coming from.

Comment: No way. I check it with different libs, it works.

Comment: Have you tested this on other pages as well? Or is it just that one page?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Yes, I have. All look the same.

Comment: have you looked into the dev tools to see what's happening? In Chrome, right click on the button, choose "Inspect". On the right-hand side look at the "Computed" tab. Scroll down to a rule (e.g. "color" or something). Click to expand the rule and it'll tell you where it sourced the instruction from. That will tell you if it's using your bootstrap file, or another source, or just the default. Then it should be straightforward to find the problem.

Comment: Please include *in the question* a complete but minimal re-create (ie. enough HTML to show the issue).

Comment: @ADyson You saved my day. Thank you so much.